# MySQL: Better way than drop and rename table?

Tags: mysql, database

I’m working on a MySQL Database and running a cronjob php script which executes a single query on the database to calculate data and replace a table in the database. The query takes about two seconds so I can’t truncate the table before I start because I want the user to see the old data as long as the new data isn’t complete. My first thought was to create a new table, run the query, drop the old table and rename the new one. Is there a better way to do that? Theoretically someone could still request data in-between my drop and rename query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform the updates in a [transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commit.html).

Until you `COMMIT` the transaction, users will see the old data.